# Java Swing FocusTraversalPolicy Issue

Tags: java, swing, focus

I'm currently having an issue with implementing a `FocusTraversalPolicy`.

I would like for the `Tab`/`Shift+Tab` keyboard shortcuts to allow for navigating top-bottom/left-right. This will allow for simpler navigation when filling in a form.

The policy should only impact all elements in the `mainPanel` of my `JFrame`.

I have implemented the policy using the following class:

```
public class DefaultViewFocusTraversalPolicy
        extends FocusTraversalPolicy
{
   ArrayList<Component> order;

   public DefaultViewFocusTraversalPolicy(ArrayList<Component> order)
   {
      this.order = order;
   }

   @Override
   public Component getComponentAfter(Container aContainer, Component aComponent)
   {
      int index = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1) % order.size();
      Component after = order.get(index);
      while (index < order.size() && !(after.isEnabled() && after.isVisible()))
      {
         index++;
         after = order.get(index);
      }
      return after;
   }

   @Override
   public Component getComponentBefore(Container aContainer, Component aComponent)
   {
      int index = order.indexOf(aComponent) - 1;
      if (index < 0)
      {
         index = order.size() - 1;
      }
      Component before = order.get(index);
      while (index >= 0 && !(before.isEnabled() && before.isVisible()))
      {
         index--;
         before = order.get(index);
      }
      return before;
   }

   @Override
   public Component getFirstComponent(Container aContainer)
   {
      int index = 0;
      Component first = order.get(index);
      while (index < order.size() && !(first.isEnabled() && first.isVisible()))
      {
         index++;
         first = order.get(index);
      }
      return first;
   }

   @Override
   public Component getLastComponent(Container aContainer)
   {
      int index = order.size() - 1;
      Component last = order.get(index);
      while (index >= 0 && !(last.isEnabled() && last.isVisible()))
      {
         index--;
         last = order.get(index);
      }
      return last;
   }

   @Override
   public Component getDefaultComponent(Container aContainer)
   {
      return getFirstComponent(aContainer);
   }
}
```

I then instantiate the class with the following inside the constructor of my view (e.g. main `JFrame`):

```
ArrayList<Component> order = new ArrayList<>();
order.add(this.ecmID);
order.add(this.modeID);
// ...
DefaultViewFocusTraversalPolicy policy =
        new DefaultViewFocusTraversalPolicy(order);
this.mainPanel.setFocusTraversalPolicy(policy);
```

However, when I try to Tab through the elements, nothing has changed and the previous policy is still in place. I've already tried going through the Java tutorial: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have solved the problem...I simply restructured the layout (as the default policy goes from right to left) so that it would focus in the direction I was looking for. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why you are even extending the **`FocusTraversalPolicy`** for your case  while default `FocusTraversalPolicy` should do the job for you.

However, you need to set **`this.mainPanel.setFocusCycleRoot(true)`**: which sets whether this Container is the root of a focus traversal cycle. Once focus enters a traversal cycle, typically it cannot leave it via focus traversal unless one of the up- or down-cycle keys is pressed. Normal traversal is limited to this Container, and all of this Container's descendants that are not descendants of inferior focus cycle roots.

You can look into the [**`ContainerOrderFocusTraversalPolicy`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/ContainerOrderFocusTraversalPolicy.html):

1. determines traversal order based on the order:returned by `Container.getComponents()`
2. From a particular focus cycle root, the policy makes a pre-order traversal of the Component hierarchy .

It has a nice function: [**`boolean accept(Component aComponent)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/ContainerOrderFocusTraversalPolicy.html#accept%28java.awt.Component%29): Determines whether a Component is an acceptable choice as the new focus owner. just override this function by extending this class, with your corresponding component list you don't want to be focused of the `Container`. *No need to override all of the function and implement them.*

Comment: When I try to `setFocusCycleRoot(true)`, I lose the ability to Tab through the elements altogether. Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting this without using the custom focus cycle. Your implementation might have fault. Try with setting the `ContainerOrderFocusTravserPolicy` as suggested above

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Component> order = new ArrayList<>();
```

I think that you looking for

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Testing {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Component[] focusList;
    private int focusNumber = 0;
    private JFrame frame;

    public Testing() {
        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(5);
        tf1.setName("tf1");
        JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(5);
        tf2.setName("tf2");
        JTextField tf3 = new JTextField(5);
        tf3.setName("tf3");
        JButton b1 = new JButton("B1");
        b1.setName("b1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("B2");
        b2.setName("b2");
        tf2.setEnabled(false);
        focusList = new Component[]{tf1, b1, tf2, b2, tf3};
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        panel.add(tf1);
        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(tf2);
        panel.add(b2);
        panel.add(tf3);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new MyFocusTraversalPolicy());
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
                        Component comp = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
                        System.out.println(comp.getName());
                        if (comp.isEnabled() == false) {
                            if (ke.isShiftDown()) {
                                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusPreviousComponent();
                            } else {
                                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy {

        @Override
        public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot, Component aComponent) {
            focusNumber = (focusNumber + 1) % focusList.length;
            return focusList[focusNumber];
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot, Component aComponent) {
            focusNumber = (focusList.length + focusNumber - 1) % focusList.length;
            return focusList[focusNumber];
        }

        @Override
        public Component getDefaultComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return focusList[0];
        }

        @Override
        public Component getLastComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return focusList[focusList.length - 1];
        }

        @Override
        public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return focusList[0];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Testing testing = new Testing();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation is correct. But would not it be much simpler if we use the `ContainerOrderFocusTraversalPolicy` and override it's accept function only.

Comment: not sure, I'm (not remember correctly, and don't want to thinking about, my endless lazyness won again :-) see there is/are side effect(s) for L&F or editable (JTextComponents)/non_editable (JButton), really I don't want to guessing about +1 for reasonable direct and clear description (??? I doubt or not, focusing is hot_potato game)

Comment: @mKobel, ha ha! yup +1 to `focusing is hot_potato game`.