# Compute focus traversal distance for two Swing components within a window

Tags: java, swing, focus

## Original Post

I'd like to programmatically determine how many keyboard strokes (doesn't matter if tab and/or arrow keys) are necessary to go from one Swing component (owns focus) to another within the current window. Each stroke should add a distance of 1; if the component can't be reached, the result should be -1.

Since I wasn't able to find an utility method, I thought about the following signature:

```
public static int getFocusTraversalDistance( Component from, Component to )
```

Naively, I'd start with getting the `Container` of `from` via [`getFocusCycleRootAncestor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getFocusCycleRootAncestor--). Afterwards, I'd fetch the `FocusTraversalPolicy` with [`getFocusTraversalPolicy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getFocusTraversalPolicy--) and loop through the components using [`getComponentAfter(Container, Component)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html#getComponentAfter-java.awt.Container-java.awt.Component-) respectively [`getComponentBefore(Container, Component)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html#getComponentBefore-java.awt.Container-java.awt.Component-).

However, I'm not that familiar with the Swing/AWT focus subsystem and I wonder if there's a more elegant way?

## Edit #1

The reason why I need this information is my master thesis, which I'm currently writing. The idea is to enhance GUI-based monkey testing with machine learning. Rather than picking random components, the trained model tries to "recommend" a component based on historical user/tester traces. One of the features I'm using for this is the focus traversal distance between the previous target component and a possible target component.

## Edit #2

Thanks to the valuable input of [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44119450/3429133), I'm currently using the following algorithm:

```
public static int getFocusTraversalDistance( Component from, Component to ) {
    if ( from.equals( to ) ) {
        return 0;
    }

    final Container root = from.getFocusCycleRootAncestor();

    if ( root == null ) {
        return -1;
    }

    final FocusTraversalPolicy policy = root.getFocusTraversalPolicy();
    final HashSet<Component> visited = new HashSet<>();
    Component before = from;
    Component after = from;
    int distance = 1;

    while ( true ) {
        if ( before != null ) {
            visited.add( before );
            before = policy.getComponentBefore(
                    before.getFocusCycleRootAncestor(), before );
            if ( to.equals( before ) ) {
                return distance;
            }
        }

        if ( after != null ) {
            visited.add( after );
            after = policy.getComponentAfter(
                    after.getFocusCycleRootAncestor(), after );
            if ( to.equals( after ) ) {
                return distance;
            }
        }

        if ( before == null && after == null
                || visited.contains( before ) && visited.contains( after ) ) {
            return -1;
        }

        distance++;
    }
}
```

So far it seems to work, but practically non-focusable components may produce strange results. The [AWT focus subsystem doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html) says that "[…] all Components return true from this [[`Component#isFocusable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isFocusable--)] method." Even components such as `JLabel` return `true`, although (AFAIK) it practically can't gain focus and [`Component#hasFocus()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#hasFocus--) is always `false`.

If someone's interested, I can setup a GitHub project with a full functional test suite.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach. The question is why do you need this information? Maybe if we know the actual requirement we can think of a different solution for the requirement.

Comment: @camickr Good point! I've added the information to the question.

Comment: `I need this information is my master thesis...` - way above my skill level. Good luck :)

Comment: maybe will help you to [add/create an array of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20201023/714968), then this array can has a historical, machines memory but still so far =! artificial intelligence, Focus is pretty asynchronous and should be wrapped inside invokeLater(can moves this event to the end of EDT)

Comment: @camickr this question is related to Swing only, don't worry—any help is appreciated. :-)

Comment: @mKorbel I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I'm not able to implement my own policy. The system under test (SUT) is not under my control, all I can do is read the information provided by the current window.

Answer (score 5):

> this question is related to Swing only, don't worry—any help is appreciated

I already stated it sounds like a reasonable approach. The only think I'm not sure of is will the approach work when you have multiple nested panels. Or at least it may get more complicated if you have to keep get the focus traversal policy for each container.

You might try looking at the `KeyboardFocusManager` to see if it can help.

The only other approach I can think of is to actually tab through all the components on the form and add each component to an `ArrayList`. Then your `getFocusTraversalDistance(...)` would use the `ArrayList` instead of the `FocusTraversalPolicy`. Of course this has the problem that the component will actually gain focus and `focusGained`/`focusLost` code could be invoked.

Or maybe combine the two approaches. That is use your approach to use the focus traversal policy, but only do this one to build the `ArrayList` when the frame is created. Then your `getFocusTraversalDistance(...)` can reference the `ArrayList`, which should make it a little more efficient.

Comment: "[…] will the approach work when you have multiple nested panels." That's my concern as well. Nonetheless, `KeyboardFocusManager` seems like a good hint. Will have a look at it and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for you help so far. Updated the answer with some more information.